# How do I prevent make clean deleting a certain file in a qmake project

Tags: qmake

I'm not sure if I did everything right, but I managed to make lupdate be run by make by adding this to my qmake project file

```
lupdate.name           = updating ts translation files
lupdate.depends        = $$_PRO_FILE_
lupdate.input          = _PRO_FILE_ $$HEADERS $$SOURCES qml/*.qml
lupdate.output         = $$PWD/translations/myproject_hu.ts
lupdate.commands       = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/lupdate ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
lupdate.CONFIG        += no_link target_predeps combine
```

now the downside of this is that translations/myproject_hu.ts gets deleted by make clean (and needs to be checked out from git again)
is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to prevent make from deleting my translations/myproject_hu.ts file?

I already have my ts files listed as DISTFILES as well, it doesn't help.

Thank you for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured out (I think) after several months of struggling.

The answer is

lupdate.CONFIG += no_link target_predeps combine **no_clean**